# How to disable textbox focusing C#

Tags: c#

i have a application where

**Scenario :**
when i click on that textbox the cursor should not point the textbox it should be disabled

how do i achieve this disabling the textbox

```
textbox1.focus()=false;
textbox1.focused()=false;
```

Comment: did you try set yourForm.ActiveControl = null? you posted same question before?

Comment: winform/WPF/Webforms??

Comment: @HienNguyen, two same questions, two same answers

Comment: When you *click on that textbox*? So, you don't want to show the caret inside the TextBox when you click on the control? Maybe, use a Label with a 3D border, instead. Is this a WinForms control?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `this.ActiveControl = null;` with this is your Form

This code no control is active and your textbox lost focus too.

```
private void YourForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{ 
    this.ActiveControl = null;       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable a textbox:

```
textBox.IsEnabled = false;
```

To not focus the textBox just focus on an other element.

For example on a Forms class:

```
this.Focus();
```